# Translate text in Ts file - Angular Ngx Translation

Tags: angular, typescript, ngx-translate

I want to translate text exist in my typescript file so each time I want to change the language while I am using the application the text should change (example change language from english to frensh). I tried the following code but didn't works

```
this.translate.get('example').subscribe(res => { this.title = res.title }
```

Also I tried this and It worked fine but I don't want to add same code in different components every time I want to translate something in typescript file when I change from language to another

```
this.translate.onLangChange.subscribe(() => {
                this.translate.get('example').subscribe(res => { this.title = res.title }
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

You should put the translate service in your app.component and make all the translates there, so you'll not need to replicane anywhere else

Comment: can you elaborate   ?

Answer (score 0):

Try constructing your title value this way :

```
this.title$: Observable<string> = this.translate.onLangChange.pipe(
  switchMapTo(this.translate.get('example')),
  map((result: string) => result.title)
)
```

Then use async pipe in your html instead of subscribing in your ts file.

If you need to translate your value programmatically. You need to listen to `onLangChange` each time. You could try to abstract this logic in a dedicated service.

My advice is to try to use the translate pipe instead of trying to set the value programmatically.

Comment: your answer isn't what i'm looking for. I want to translate only in typescript file so I don't need the pipe